# Issue with GPG keys while setting up a proot environment

Tags: application-development, pbuilder

I am trying to set up a chroot environment with `pbuilder`. I tried this but got the following issue.

```
$ sudo pbuilder create --distribution focal
W: /root/.pbuilderrc does not exist
I: Distribution is focal.
I: Current time: Tue Sep  8 12:15:34 IST 2020
I: pbuilder-time-stamp: 1599547534
I: Building the build environment
I: running debootstrap
/usr/sbin/debootstrap
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Checking Release signature
E: Release signed by unknown key (key id A507B2BBA7803E3B)
   The specified keyring /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg may be incorrect or out of date.
   You can find the latest Debian release key at https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html
E: debootstrap failed
E: Tail of debootstrap.log:
2020-09-08 12:15:35 URL:http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/foliate/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease [17512/17512] -> "/var/cache/pbuilder/build/32477/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_apandada1_foliate_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease" [1]
gpgv: Signature made Mon Jul  6 16:09:04 2020 IST
gpgv:                using RSA key A507B2BBA7803E3B
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
E: End of debootstrap.log
W: Aborting with an error
```

I have tried importing that key with `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A507B2BBA7803E3B`, but that did not change the output of `sudo pbuilder create --distribution focal`.

I have also tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/571970/124466), but the command

```
sudo pbuilder --debootstrapopts --keyring=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg --distribution focal
```

does not help, it only outputs how to use pbuilder.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this.

```
pbuilder-dist  focal amd64 create
```

The added advantage of this method is that both the distribution and the architecture can be altered.